# How do I enable tcpwrapper (hosts.deny) filter in mysqld / mariadb

Tags: iptables, denyhosts, mysql

How do I enable tcpwrapper (hosts.deny) filter in mysqld / mariadb

prefered solution without recompiling.

Using Debian, MariaDB 5.5 64 bit

-
Or should I just use iptables?

What's faster and what is the largest amount of ip's I can block without slowing down my server? I need to block about 10k ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You should recompile as tcpwrapper support is not usually built by default. Otherwise use iptables.